# How do you match strings from two files?

Tags: string, perl, match

I always get this error `"Use of uninitialized value $_ in print at finalhash.pl line 27, <$_[...]> line 7"` when compiling this Perl code. But my example file doesn't have a line 7.

I want to print out the entire rows of file2.txt if the strings in first column matches with the strings in in second column of file1.txt.

The columns are separated by semicolons.

This code I adapted from another answer on a question I posted before (thanks to Borodin). Can someone tell me why in the first while loop the second column was given the value 1: `"$wanted{$fields[1]} = 1;"`?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $fh;
my %wanted;

open $fh, '<', 'file1.txt';
chomp $fh;
while (my $line = <$fh>) {

    my @fields = split(';', $line);

    $wanted{$fields[1]} = 1;

}


open $fh, '<', 'file2.txt';
chomp $fh;
while (my $line = <$fh>) {

my @fields = split(';', $line);

   print if $wanted{$fields[0]};  #line 27 with the error


}

close $fh;
```

Comment: Try `print $line if $wanted{$fields[0]};` for line 27.

Comment: Thanks that helped me a lot but why do I get this error all the time: "Use of uninitialized value $fields[1] in hash element at script.pl line 15, <$_[...]> line .."?

Comment: That would happen when you split a line with no semi colon in it. `@fields` would only have 1 element, so `$fields[1]` would be undefined, since that refers to the second element.

Comment: hello, how can I avoid this error?

Comment: Check to make sure `@fields` has a length of 2 or more before you try to access the 2nd element. `if ( $#fields > 1 ) { $wanted{$fields[1]} = 1; }`

Answer (score 1):

```
open $fh, '<', 'file1.txt';
#chomp $fh;
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    chomp $line;


open $fh, '<', 'file2.txt';
#chomp $fh;
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
```

With these changes, your script should run fine. In the first file read, you didn't 'chomp' $line. chomp $fh is meaningless - does nothing.

No need to remove the newline in file 2, because you are just going to print it out later.

**Update**: Matt got the problem in the comments above. print $line if ...

Comment: thank you very much, but why do I always get the error: "Use of uninitialized value $fields[1] in hash element at script.pl line 15, <$_[...]> line .." on all the lines in which the matching pattern is not found? What can I do to get rid of this error because obviously the code works for a small set of data, test data of 4 lines (also with the error when the matching pattern is not found but with output) but when I apply the code to a bigger set of data there's no output only lots of the same error for lots of lines.